# Unity Transform,position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am facing an issue as follow:

The circle is located [circle location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AljF.png) before play the game.

when press play it goes to another place as shown here
[after press play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBT3G.png)

here is the code I am using, im pretty sure its a if statement issue:

```
public class circularmouse : MonoBehaviour {
[SerializeField] float timeCounter = 0;
[SerializeField]bool Direction = false;
[SerializeField] float angularSpeed = 0f;

public Vector3 startPosition;

private void Start()
{
    startPosition = transform.position;
}




void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        angularSpeed = 4f;
        Direction = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        Direction = false;
        angularSpeed = 4f;
    }
    if (Direction) //if direction is true
    {
        timeCounter += Time.deltaTime * angularSpeed;
        float x = Mathf.Cos(timeCounter);
        float y = Mathf.Sin(timeCounter);
        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        timeCounter -= Time.deltaTime * angularSpeed;
        float x = Mathf.Cos(timeCounter);
        float y = Mathf.Sin(timeCounter);
        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
    }
```

your help is appreciated

Comment: So, without doing anything, `direction` will be false. This means that the `else` statement is executed. `timeCounter` is initially `0` and is reduced by `deltaTime` (which is about 0.02). Sin(-0.02) is about 0 and Cos(-0.02) is about 1. Ergo, your circle moves to `(1, 0, 0)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but what about the statment in the Start class that says, keep the original position as is.

Comment: You mean `startPosition` which is never used? Your IDE should have given you a warning about this.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that since Direction is initially false, you are immediately going to this line:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
```

which is setting your transform to the position (1, 0, 0).

Not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but maybe you instead mean to add the coordinates to the position?

```
transform.position += new Vector3(x, y, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, but why it is not taking the start class into consideration

Comment: all you've done is assign the original position to a variable called startPosition, but you aren't doing anything with that variable.